# JS: can you use 2-pointer method for the stock price question

Tags: javascript

I am trying to code my own solution to the standard question of finding the max profit you can get given that each array index represents the stock price for a day. The answer for `[10, 7, 5, 8, 11, 9, 1]` would be `6` since you can buy at 5 and sell at 11, so that would give the max of 6.  My solution works for *this* scenario but when I try some test cases, it doesn't work on all.  Would a 2 pointer solution not be ideal?

```
function calc(arr) {
  //var arr1 = [10, 7, 5, 8, 11, 9, 1]
  let start = 0;
  let end = arr.length - 1
  let max = -1;
  while(start < end) {
    
     if (arr[end] - arr[start] < 0) {
        end--
     } else {
        max = Math.max(max, arr[end] - arr[start])
        start++
     }
  }
  return max;

 }
```

Comment: Can you buy and sell multiple times? Or is this a one buy/one sell? Also, please post an example of where you don't get the correct answer and what is the expected answer.

Comment: @RyanWilson `calc([4,5,6,99,2,4,91])` ..I'd expect `96` as the result since I can buy at `4` and sell at `99` but my function returns `87`

Answer (score 1):

1. Take cumulative minimum from left
2. Take cumulative maximum from right
3. Subtract minimum from maximum for each index
4. Take the maximum of the difference

```js
const nums = [10, 7, 5, 8, 11, 9, 1];

const cumMin = (arr) => {
  let ans = [];
  let prev = arr[0];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    prev = Math.min(prev, arr[i]);
    ans.push(prev);
  }
  return ans;
};

const revCumMax = (arr) => {
  arr.reverse();
  let ans = [];
  let prev = arr[0];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    prev = Math.max(arr[i], prev);
    ans.push(prev);
  }
  return ans.reverse();
};

let cMin = cumMin(nums);
let cMax = revCumMax(nums);
let diff = cMax.map((val, ind) => val - cMin[ind]);
console.log(Math.max(...diff));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build an array of local minima and maxima and get the result of all pairs (buy/sell).

```js
const
    data = [10, 7, 5, 8, 11, 9, 1],
    result = data.reduce((r, v, i, a) => {
        if (!(r.length & 1) === a[i - 1] < v) {
            r[r.length - 1] = v;
        } else {
            r.push(v);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```